# Pick random items from list without iterations

Tags: ruby

I have the following code in Rails

```
@related = []
while @related.compact.size < 3
  @tag = @car.tag_list.sample #pick a tag from the @car's tag_list
  @sametags = Car.tagged_with(@tag) # get all cars with that tag
  @related.push(( @sametags - Array(@car) - @related.compact).sample) #put that car in @related
  @counter = @counter + 1 #increment
  break if @counter == 10 #stop if its taking too long
end
```

I am well aware this code is highly inefficient, but my ruby chops aren't up for it yet...

basically what I need to have done is to populate `@related` with 3 Car models with similar tags randomly in way which they will not repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use random ordering to do this.

```
@related = Car.limit(3).order('rand()').tagged_with('blood red')
```

UPDATE: without @car

```
@tag = @car.tag_list.sample
@related = Car.where('id != ?', @car.id).limit(3).order('rand()').tagged_with(@tag)
```

UPDATE: if you are using acts_as_taggable_on

```
@related = Car.where('id != ?', @car.id).limit(3).order('rand()')
  .tagged_with(@car.tag_list, any: true)
```

Comment: but this might also select @car itself

Comment: try my updated answer. it basically excludes `@car`. and also uses all the tag list of car :)

Comment: `order('rand()`)` is not cross-DB, IIRC.

Comment: I use `sample(3)` instead of `order('rand()')`

Answer (score 2):

[Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) accepts a number, size of the sample. So I think, your code can be simplified to this:

```
@tag = @car.tag_list.sample
@sametags = Car.tagged_with(@tag)
@related = (@sametags - [@car]).sample(3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use scramble to shuffle the array first and then just pick the top three items.

```
[1,2,3,4].scramble => [3,1,2,4]
```

Comment: Could you post a link to documentation of `Array#scramble` method?